# CSS Drop Menu Issue (IE Only)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Having a bit of an issue with a CSS drop menu showing up strangely in IE 7 & 8. Basically, the styling is coming across, but there is a delay that looks related to the positioning of the child menus. At initial hover, the child menu is positioned incorrectly.

Then, once I honestly just jiggle the mouse around, it sets itself in the correct place.

Once I have done that, the other menu items fall in line, but with a slight delay. Any ideas as to what the deal is here?

The site working is http://new.layrenewal.com

Could the following scripts be conflicting: (PIE & IE.js)?

Comment: I'm not seeing any of the "jiggling" you mention, but you do have a Javascript error. 

Message: 'undefined' is null or not an object
Line: 55
Char: 143
Code: 0
URI: http://new.layrenewal.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.2

Comment: Thanks @dmackerman. I am not getting the same error, though. Here is a look at how it looks when I initially hover: http://cl.ly/2g0w1w1Y0w1r2X0y0O3O. Then, here is a look at it when I move the mouse off and back on a couple of times after it "jiggles": http://cl.ly/0J2T0O1a0f2Q4137352L. This is the way it should look initially, but it's the first rollover that's out of whack.

Excuse my terms "jiggle" & "out of whack". I'm a little fresh on development so, bare with me. :)

Answer (score 0):

if you remove the `position:relative` from `#dropmenu` ?

Comment: Thanks for the help Sotiris, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Hmm, I am using IE8 and it's still offsetting on initial hover. So it's not offsetting at all for you initially? Like this: http://cl.ly/2g0w1w1Y0w1r2X0y0O3O